# How to remove trailing slash for '/folder/index.html', when 'index.html' is stripped?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

I have a static site with the following file/folder structure:

- index.html
- /foobar/

  - index.html
  - bob.html
  - alice.html

I'd like to achieve the following:

- remove all `.html` extensions. **✔ works**
- remove `index.html` (resp. `index`). **✔ works**
- I want files to end without trailing slash. **✔ works**

  - if someone adds a trailing slash, redirect to URL without trailing slash. **✘ doesn't work**
- I want "folders" (actually `index.html` files inside a folder) to end without trailing slash. **✘ doesn't work**

  - if someone adds a trailing slash, redirect to URL without trailing slash. **✘ doesn't work**

So the following URLs should work:

- `example.com/` (actually: `/index.html`)
- `example.com/foobar` (actually: `/foobar/index.html`)
- `example.com/foobar/bob` (actually: `/foobar/bob.html`)
- `example.com/foobar/alice` (actually: `/foobar/alice.html`)

The following requests should redirect (301):

- `example.com/foobar/` redirects to: `example.com/foobar`)
- `example.com/foobar/bob/` redirects to: `example.com/foobar/bob`)
- `example.com/foobar/alice/` redirects to: `example.com/foobar/alice`)

I see that this would create a problem when a file `/foobar.html` exists: when someone visits `/foobar`, it is not clear whether the directory or the file is requested. However, I will make sure that this never happens.

---

At the moment, I have this `.htaccess`:

```
# Turn MultiViews off. (MultiViews on causes /abc to go to /abc.ext.) 
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# It stops DirectorySlash from being processed if mod_rewrite isn't. 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Disable mod_dir adding missing trailing slashes to directory requests.
    DirectorySlash Off

    RewriteEngine On

    # If it's a request to index(.html) 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
    # Remove it. 
    RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]

    # Add missing trailing slashes to directories if a matching .html does not exist. 
    # If it's a request to a directory. 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
    # And a HTML file does not (!) exist.
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
    # And there is not trailing slash redirect to add it. 
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    # Remove HTML extensions. 
    # If it's a request from a browser, not an internal request by Apache/mod_rewrite. 
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    # And the request has a HTML extension. Redirect to remove it. 
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the request exists with a .html extension. 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
    # And there is no trailing slash, rewrite to add the .html extension. 
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

What would I have to change/remove/add in my `.htaccess`? I don't understand much of it. I tried to remove the block commented "Add missing trailing slashes to directories if a matching .html does not exist", but this didn't help.

Comment: FWIW, I asked over at Code Review for possible improvements: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/18440/16414

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right above your `# Add missing trailing slashes to directories if a matching .html does not exist.` rule, try adding this rule that redirects when there is an html file and the request is NOT a directory AND there's a trailing slash:

```
# if request has a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/$
# but it isn't a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
# and if the trailing slash is removed and a .html appended to the end, it IS a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
# redirect without trailing slash
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

This shouldn't conflict with the redirect rule following it because its conditions check for the exact opposite.

---

EDIT:

To handle the index.html thing, you need to change this rule that you have, which is appending the trailing slashes:

```
# Add missing trailing slashes to directories if a matching .html does not exist. 
# If it's a request to a directory. 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
# And a HTML file does not (!) exist.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
# And there is not trailing slash redirect to add it. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

To:

```
# Add missing trailing slashes to directories if a matching .html does not exist. 
# If it's a request to a directory. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d
# And a HTML file does not (!) exist.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
# And there is not trailing slash redirect to add it. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This checks that the `index.html` file is **missing** from the directory before adding the trailing slash. The reason you *must* have this is because of the [information disclosure security issue when missing the trailing slash will actually expose all of your directory contents if you don't have the trailing slash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). Now, add these rules to remove the trailing slash when there's an `index.html`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is a trailing slash redirect to remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now add these rules right after to explicitly display the `index.html` when there is no trailing slash (note no `R=301` in the rule's flags):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is no trailing slash show the index.html. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. It works. I marked this point in my answer as working. Do you also have an idea how to get the other two points working?

Comment: @unor This rule takes care of all 3 of the "doesn't work" points, that's why there's all the extra conditions. Works for me, either that or I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Hmm, if I visit `example.com/foobar` (without trailing slash), I get redirected to `example.com/foobar/` (with trailing slash). I want to show the file `/foobar/index.html`, but with URL `/foobar`.

Comment: @unor did you manage to do you redirect to only show `/foobar`?